# How to start ordered list (IE8) with start or value?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, list, html-lists, border

I have a website which has a list of posts that numbers from 1 to 50. It works in Chrome, Firefox and IE 10, but not in IE 8 or lower....

I have this one: `<ol id="post-list" class="lol" start="1">`

CSS:

```
#entry-list > li:before {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    color: gray;
    content: attr(value);
    width: 100%;
}

#entry-list {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-top: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

    #entry-list .content{margin-bottom:10px}
#entry-list>li{position:relative}
#entry-list>li:not(:last-child){margin-bottom:30px}
```

The problem: no border-bottom in IE 8 (or lower) and no attribute/value/ list starting with 1. How can I make it work? Why does my **IE-specific stylesheet** not respond to `#entry-list > li:before`?

Answer (score 0):

See if this answer helps, for the :before issue: [How can I get IE8 to accept a CSS :before tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546251/how-can-i-get-ie8-to-accept-a-css-before-tag)

As for "start" ... it should be working. Are you using any css normalization when doing this? We'd kind of need to see more code, however, to take a look. You do realize, however, that the CSS you posted would target an object with the id of entry-list, not post-list, right?

Comment: Well, this is the code that matters and I can't think any other code you might need? The :before statement does not work for some reason. I am using the compatibility view of IE, maybe that is the problem...

Anyhow, thanks for your answer.