# I can't get IE8 to support :before

Tags: html, css

No idea why :before won't work. My IE8 browser will display it correctly on this page:

http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/beforeafter.html

but not when I do it on this page:

http://africa.ie

Comment: Do you have `<!DOCTYPE>` definition?

Comment: Yes see source of http://africa.ie

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546251/how-can-i-get-ie8-to-accept-a-css-before-tag

Comment: I think might be root of problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867383/css-renders-differently-on-web-server-than-on-development-environment

Comment: A question should include code needed to reproduce the problem. A link to a live page is *not* enough.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does support `:before`.

Two possibilities:

1. IE is rendering the page in compatibility mode or quirks mode.

   Either of these modes will disable this functionality. Add a valid doctype and set `X-UA-Compatible` to `IE=edge` to deal with this.
2. You're using `::before` rather than `:before`.

   This is quite a subtle one. The correct syntax is with a double-colon, but at the time IE8 was released, it was a single colon; the official syntax has been changed subsequently. All modern browsers will accept either single or double colon for `::before` and `::after` to accommodate this historical change, but IE8 is stuck only supporting the single colon.

Comment: 1. Done. See http://africa.ie
2. Done. I'm using single colon :before. See http://africa.ie

Comment: @JuanCullen not sure if this'll help, but could try removing ::before all together?  I see you are now declaring both :before and ::before.

Answer (score 0):

it works as long as you aren't in compatability mode.  If you want it to support more I might recommend the following:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: The problem isn't compatibility mode, I can confirm that it's running in IE8 standards.

Comment: I tried this and I get popup warning 
'This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?'

Comment: then download the file and don't host it off of google's cdn.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `::before` and `::after` selectors seems to get it work in IE8:

```
p.test:before {
    padding-right: 5px;
    content: url(http://quirksmode.org/pix/logo_ppk.gif);
}
p.test:after {
    font-style: italic;
    content: " and some text after.";
}
```

Comment: cool - I suspected this but didn't have IE8 to test on.  Maybe it would also work to do `p.test::before, p.test:before {}` instead of the reverse order.

Comment: Yes but since they are equivalent (`::before` is CSS3, `:before` is CSS2) it doesn't really matter. IE8 only supports `:before` but modern browsers support both.

Comment: in theory it _shouldn't_ matter, but `p.test:before, p.test::before {}` was causing problems in IE8.  I was just suggesting to try the reverse and see if it helps, if OP wants to include both.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying there's no reason to use `::before` at all. "The ::before notation was introduced in CSS 3 in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept the notation :before introduced in CSS 2." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: agreed.  But maybe someday a browser won't accept :before?  Or maybe OP just wants it in there for the heck of it.  who knows.